# SpringBoot, test containers to test queries sent to external DB

Tags: spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa, testcontainers, multi-database

My Spring app has its own DB for persistence. 
The same app needs to send ad-hoc queries to external databases. 
Queries are provided by users.

- App takes SQL query provided by user
- App takes external database type (postgres / oracle / whatever jdbc)
- App submits adhoc query in runtime to external DB
- App returns result as json to user

Is there any way to utilize spring test containers in order to test this functionaly?
My goal is:

- Write tests for every supported DB
- each test starts test container with supported DB (some subset of these I suppose: https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/)
- each test uploads sample data to container DB
- each test runs set of "must work" queries against it.

I see many examples where App itself is tested against test containers, but can I just start container w/o plugging it as App persistence DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I just start container w/o plugging it as App persistence DB?

Yes, this is perfectly possible.
Testcontainers in itself has nothing to do with Spring or Spring Boot.

What you would do is:

- pick the container you want to use (different container for different databases
- instantiate the container
- start it up
- construct a `DataSource` from it
- Use that `DataSource` for your tests.

Spring Data JDBC does exactly that to run tests against various databases.
I add [the class doing that for MySQL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/master/spring-data-jdbc/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/testing/MySqlDataSourceConfiguration.java) in the end.
It is a Spring application context configuration, but you could put that in a JUnit before method, a JUnit 4 rule or a JUnit 5 extension or just a normal method that you call at the start of your test.

```java
@Configuration
@Profile("mysql")
class MySqlDataSourceConfiguration extends DataSourceConfiguration {

    private static final MySQLContainer MYSQL_CONTAINER = new MySQLContainer().withConfigurationOverride("");

    static {
        MYSQL_CONTAINER.start();
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.jdbc.testing.DataSourceConfiguration#createDataSource()
     */
    @Override
    protected DataSource createDataSource() {

        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(MYSQL_CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl());
        dataSource.setUser(MYSQL_CONTAINER.getUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(MYSQL_CONTAINER.getPassword());
        dataSource.setDatabaseName(MYSQL_CONTAINER.getDatabaseName());

        return dataSource;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initDatabase() throws SQLException, ScriptException {
        ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(createDataSource().getConnection(), null, "DROP DATABASE test;CREATE DATABASE test;");
    }
}
```